# How to add .hover function to a image in a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a HTML generated by Sharepoint. I added a table and few images and I would like to add `.hover` to a selected image. After a long suffering I can select the image by using `.querySelector`, but if I try:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
      document.querySelector('.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img').hover(function ()
      {
        $(this).css('opacity', '.3');
      }, function ()
      {
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
      });
    });
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).hover is not a function". I added Jquery so that can't be the reason. (Most of the related topics advice to add it)

If I try `.onmouseover`:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  document.querySelector('.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img').onmouseover = function()
  {
   $(this).css('opacity', '.3');
  }
});
```

This works, but the effect is permanent, so even if the mouse leave the image the transparency remains 30%. So I would like to use `.hover`, but I am not experienced so I have no idea what can be the problem, pls lend me a hand.

Comment: You can use CSS also for hover

Comment: If you are going with mouseover, you also have mouseout events where you can reset opacity again

Comment: Yeah, I posted the .onmouseover version to show the selector is working well so something else is the problem. Thanks you very much all for the fast problem solving. I got several good answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a jQuery method **.hover()** on a DOM selected element **document.querySelector()**.

You can only call jQuery methods on jQuery objects. Use jQuery for your selector in order to get a jQuery object which you can then call the hover method on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '.3');
  }, function () {
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
  });
});
```

Comment: @Nefri no worries. I would suggest using CSS for this if possible as CSS is the most resource efficient way to do this. However, if you just need something that works then this will do just fine! :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img:hover {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

Comment: I tested this and works well. Thanks you very much! Looks like I can accept only 1 answer, so I accepted the javascript version, by Felipe, but this is working too.

Comment: Next time for such tasks it is better to use CSS. JavaScript is redundant

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the error, when adding jQuery you need to use its own engine to have access to the `hover` function (*it does not extend the native objects*).

So use

```
jQuery('.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img').hover(function ()
```

on the other hand you could just use CSS

```
.ms-rteTableEvenCol-0 > a > img:hover{
   opacity:0.3;
}
```

Comment: I tested this solution too. This is working very well both the javascript and CSS suggestions. Thanks you very much for the fast response!